# How do I fill and submit a form remotely?

Tags: javascript, python

How can I fill out and submit this form remotely: http://mta-nyc.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/mta_nyc.cfg/php/enduser/ask.php

The form asks for email and then it has a pull down menu and fields for Subject and Question.

Clicking the Next button takes you to a new page and in that page you click submit.

Can I fill this form and submit with one click from my site?

I will have a form in my site where the user will fill out his email and I will have pre-populated fields for Subject and Question and when the user will click the submit button the remote form will be filled and submitted.

How can I do this (with python and javascript)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are submitting the page to your python backend, check out [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).

Comment: I am using Google App Engine and I am planning to create a page which will have pre-populated fields for "Subject" and "Question" and take the user email and submit to that remote form. So, I am not sure what you mean by "submitting page to your python backend". I would like to submit the remote form from a Google App Engine app using Python. Thanks.

Comment: Python is your back end than. If you are doing a POST on your page to submit the data than you would want to send it via python and return the response that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try twill - http://twill.idyll.org/python-api.html. I't some wrapper of Mechanize.

Comment: Thanks, I read the documentation but I don't exactly understand how it all works. Do you know any sources where this is explained in a more elementary basic way or how to achieve the same without Mechanize or twill? (Just to give me an idea how it all works)

Answer (score 0):

Issue a post to ~/api/feedback with the same headers and form data that their form produces?

Open up Chrome dev tools or whatever, go to the network tab, fill out the form manually once and copy the last HTTP POST?

Depending on the type of feedback on that form, the data will change. The data I posted looks like:

```
feedback: {"name":{"first":"Test","last":"Test"},"email":"test@test.co","feedbackType":{"service":{"sid1":10000,"sid2":14000},"categories":{"cid1":14308}},"attributes":[{"id":"branch_line_route","value":"F"},{"id":"traincarnumber","value":"1"},{"id":"date_of_event","value":"2020-09-10T13:35:47.318Z"},{"id":"time_of_occurence","value":"15:37:37"}],"comment":"Nice train"}
```